# Autowire Spring Bean in Camel JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel

I'm trying to integrate Camel with Spring 5 (using annotations - no XML!) and am having some trouble with my JUnit tests. I am able to launch Camel when the JUnit runs, but the Spring controller object I am trying to invoke as part of the test is not getting autowired.

My Junit is below;

```
public class ListCaseNotesTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext acc = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        acc.register(CamelController.class);
        return acc;
    }

    @Autowired
    VisitsController visitsController;

    @Test
    public void testListCaseNotes() throws Exception{

        ListNotesKey listNotesKey = new ListNotesKey();
        listNotesKey.setUsername("caseworker");
        listNotesKey.setRelatedIDs("[\"1000\",\"1001\",\"1002\"]");
        listNotesKey.setRelatedType(ListNotesKey.RelatedTypeEnum.CASE);

        // invoke camel
        String response = visitsController.sendMessage("listCaseNotes", SOR_CONFIG, payload);
```

I've ommitted the response validation for brevity - the exception I receive is a NullPointerException when the sendMessage is invoked. The full log is below;

```
Mar 01, 2018 3:53:04 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'visitsRouteBuilder' of type [com.me.camel.routes.VisitsRouteBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Mar 01, 2018 3:53:04 PM org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'camelController' of type [com.me.camel.CamelController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c13afa5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
[                          main] ManagedManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is enabled
[                          main] DefaultTypeConverter           INFO  Type converters loaded (core: 192, classpath: 1)
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: direct://visits
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.443 seconds
[                          main] ListCaseNotesTest              INFO  ********************************************************************************
[                          main] ListCaseNotesTest              INFO  Testing done: testListCaseNotes(com.me.test.notes.ListCaseNotesTest)
[                          main] ListCaseNotesTest              INFO  Took: 0.034 seconds (34 millis)
[                          main] ListCaseNotesTest              INFO  ********************************************************************************
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[                          main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 10 seconds)
[el-1) thread #1 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://visits
[                          main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
Mar 01, 2018 3:53:05 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@e056f20: startup date [Thu Mar 01 15:53:04 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 01, 2018 3:53:05 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor stop
INFO: Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.496 seconds
[                          main] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.017 seconds

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.test.notes.ListCaseNotesTest.testListCaseNotes(ListCaseNotesTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

What do I need to do to set up my JUnit test such that the Spring bean is autowired successfully?

Thanks in advance!

Bic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html the `CamelSpringTestSupport` doesn't process the Spring annotations. If you insist on extending it you could get your context from `applicationContext` field and manually get the right bean:

`applicationContext.getBean(VisitsController.class).sendMessage("listCaseNotes", SOR_CONFIG, payload)`

Alternatively switch to Cammel runner `@RunWith(org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you insist on extending..."? I'm just trying to get this test to work so am happy to do it in whatever way makes the most sense! :-)

Comment: I have tried agetting the bean from the applicationContext as you recommend and I receive a "No qualifying bean of type 'com.me.controllers.VisitsController' available" message :-(

Comment: Normally it's either using `@RunWith` with correct runner or extending a support class. I'd prefer to use `@RunWith` as it feels more modern and Spring `@Autowired` or `@DiretiesContext` annotations are very handy. This is however entirely up to you, first make the test run then refactor.

Comment: This is expected. You are creating the context manually so you need to add the `VisitsController` bean and any other nested bean referenced by `VisitsController` manually. So far you only added `CamelController`.

It all depends on how you are creating your running application and what do you want to test. If you are writing a test just for `VisitsController` it might be handy to have a simple context with this bean. If you want to write a full integration test you might want to use Spring package scanning.

Comment: Adding package scanning to CamelController and pulling the VisitsController instance from the applicationContext instead of AutoWiring worked - thanks!